# Looking for Sci Fi novel about faster than light travel using "EMC clamps"

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a series of science fiction books I read in middle school. They would have been published before 1970. I am very fuzzy on the details, but here is what I do remember:

- I think the series may have had a British author.  Many of the main characters used "Sir" as a title.
- In one book, featuring faster-than-light travel, a reference was made to "EMC clamps" which made the FTL travel possible.
- In the same book, as the ship approached the speed of light, the crew experienced blurred vision that had to do with this particular FTL mechanism. (Sounds hokey, I know. But it's one of the details I remember.)

Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: How certain are you about the "EMC Clamps"?

Comment: It was a long time ago, so it's hard to say.  If not exact, it should be close. I was old enough to have heard of the e = mc^2 equation, so I understood the connection and I could see how the name made sense in this context.  It's possible it could have been something like "MC-squared clamps."  I'm almost certain the name used "clamps" in it.

Comment: Blurred vision is experience by characters aboard a starship in EC Tubb's 'Escape Into Space' No reference to EMC clamps though. Also the crew in Charles Carr's 'Colonists of Space' experienced sensory issues at high speeds, but again no mention of EMC clamps.